# What did Voldemort do during Harry's sixth year?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

We have no mention of Voldemort in Harry's sixth year. So, I was wondering- what could Voldemort have been doing?

Comment: Well we know it wasn't plastic surgery or anger-management classes.

Comment: @Richard - in prior books, he tortures kittens for fun. In DH, he refrains from killing a muggle child because it's "not necessary" (and then proceeds to not kill Neville). I say anger management classes is indeed an answer.

Comment: @dvk - *‘The Dark Lord is very angry,’ repeated Snape*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Although the general answer to this is "marshalling his dark forces and preparing to take over the wizarding world", there are, as you've mentioned, precious few direct mentions of Lord Voldemort in HP and the Half-Blood Prince.

Let's have a look at what we can say that he's **definitely** been up to, as opposed to stuff that *could* be the work of his minions:

- **Practicing his occlumency**

> It appears that he is now employing Occlumency against you [said Dumbledore]

- **Being "at large"** (i.e not getting caught)

> ‘Now, as everybody in this Hall knows, Lord Voldemort and his
>   followers are once more at large and gaining in strength.’

- **Being angry**

> ‘The Dark Lord is very angry,’ repeated Snape quietly.

- **Meeting with Snape**

> ‘But what use have you been?’ sneered Bellatrix. ‘What useful
>   information have we had from you?’   **‘My information has been conveyed
>   directly to the Dark Lord,’** said Snape. ‘If he chooses not to share it
>   with you –’

- **Recruiting werewolves**

> Fenrir Greyback is, perhaps, the most savage werewolf alive today. He
>   regards it as his mission in life to bite and to contaminate as many
>   people as possible; he wants to create enough werewolves to overcome
>   the wizards. **Voldemort has promised him prey in return for his
>   services.**

- **Ordering Draco to kill Dumbledore**

> ‘And, should it prove necessary … if it seems Draco will fail …’
>   whispered Narcissa (Snape’s hand twitched within hers, but he did not
>   draw away), ‘will you carry out the deed that the Dark Lord has
>   ordered Draco to perform?’

Comment: Gee - makes me wish I could flag this as 'ridiculously awesome' ;)  Brilliant as always!